# proper test for indifference of two groups

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, modeling, proportion

I'm reaching out with a question that, at first glance, might seem elementary, but given some perplexing advice from my thesis supervisor, I find myself in need of your expertise.

The scenario is straightforward: we have two groups of shooters, each with 100 participants. Every shooter takes 10 shots, and each shot is either a success or a failure.

I aim to determine if there's a significant difference in shooting accuracy between the two groups. My initial approach was to calculate the individual success rates and then compare these rates using a t-test. However, my mentor has indicated that this method is not suitable for analyzing proportions. On the other hand, if I use a proportion test (like prop.test or Fisher's exact test), I must consider each shot as an independent event, which doesn't seem correct since each shooter takes multiple shots.

I'm currently feeling uncertain and wonder if I might have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of some sophisticated approaches that might work better (e.g., shooter as a random effect in a logistic regression), but sticking two groups of $100$ counts of hits into a two-sample t-test seems like it would be a solid approach. Since that just multiplies the values by the ten shots taken instead of using the proportion of hits (since everyone takes ten shots), this isn’t fundamentally different from what you seem to have proposed.

If your advisor gripes about a t-test requiring normality of the two groups as well as equal variance:

1. Welch’s t-test, which is the default in R software through `t.test`, handles the case where equal variances are not safe to assume (which I think it is not safe to assume here).
2. Both the usual and Welch t-test are quite robust to deviations from normality.
3. The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U test (`wilcox.test` in R) could be a viable alternative.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. However, it seems that my thesis supervisor instead looks for something like a proportion test. He gave me a link for that: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.4. It is a bit strange for me, as if I go with proportion test, then I need to aggregate all shooters' attempts to derive the proportion. This assumes that each shoot is independent of other shoots, which is wrong (each shooter takes 10 attempts). Any thoughts here?

Comment: I think your supervisor is mistaken and that my post is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you say in the question, the problem is the multiple tries for each shooter. Without that complication, the data could be presented as a contingency table and some test such as chi-square or Fisher exact test be used.

The usual thing to do here would be using a random effect for each shooter, that is, a (binomial) mixed effects model. You should have enough observations for that to be possible. Illustrating with some R code:

```r
library(lme4)
mod0 <- glmer( success ~ Group + (1 | shooter), family=binomial, 
               data=your_data_frame)
summary(mod0)
```

But, probably, the advice given by @Dave is simpler and would probably lead to the same conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to model this would be to use the (binomial) counts you observe and these are independent across shooters. As in:

```
nsucces <- c(6,7,8,8,9, 2,3,1,4,6)
group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

model <- glm(cbind(nsucces,10-shoot) ~ group, family=binomial)
summary(model)
```

So a random effect across shooters is not immediately required. Since your dependent variable is a count (out of 10, or a proportion if you like), why not analyze it as such? Then you have no issues with whether t is suited here or not.

Comment: But formally, this assumes that the binomial probabilities are constant within each group. If not, that could be seen as overdispersion

Comment: Yes, @kjetil, you are right, that could be tested indeed, but such overdispersion maybe not always exist.